# Angular Form Validation On Dynamically Added And Removed Form Fields In Angular 1.5.7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-forms

So I have read a few posts on this topic and haven't quite figured it out. I tried to implement the solution found at https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform but had no success. the validation does add the ng-invalid class to the element but it does not show the error message using ng-show. Heres what I've got so far.

First off here's a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/0Xh0o82N1xQc7Qi5Mhfe?p=preview

```
<h1>Dynamic Field</h1>
<div ng-controller="EmailCtrl">
  <hr>
  <a ng-click="addEmail()" href="#">Add Email</a>
  <hr>
  <form name="email_form">
    <label>Main Form
    <input type="email" ng-model="test.email" name="email" />
    <div class="help-block" ng-show="email_form.email.$touched">
    <span ng-show="email_form.email.$error.email">ERROR</span>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <div ng-repeat="email in emails">
    <ng-form="sub_form">
      sub form <input name="sub_email" type="email" ng-model="email.email" />
      <div class="help-block" ng-show="sub_form.sub_email.$touched">
        <span ng-show="sub_form.sub_email.$error.email">ERROR</span>
      </div>
      <a ng-click="removeEmail($index)" href="#">Remove Email</a>
      </ng-form>
  </div>
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ng-form="sub_form>
</ng-form>
```

should be:

```
<ng-form name="sub_form">
</ng-form>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: yup...its always something so simple...i really hate it when i miss a friggin semi-colon..lol

Comment: @OGJoshZero it took me about 30 minutes :)